# how to pass variables many level down in mongdb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I don't know how to pass specific variables (report id) many levels down in MongoDB aggregation, I'm using a filter to filter the array on user document based on report id, so I want to pass the report id to get only objects that owned by this report
the snippet will explain what exactly I want to do

```js
const reports = await Report.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'operations',
          let: { operationId: '$operation', reportId: '$_id' /* I don't know if this is right or if there's a better way to get the report id */ },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$operationId'] } },
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                let: {
                  userId: '$initiator.user', type: '$initiator.type'},
                pipeline: [
                  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$userId'] } } },
                  {
                    $project: {
                      color: '$colorCode.code',
                      avatar: 1,
                      type: '$$type',
                      clear: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: '$clear',
                          as: 'clear',
                          cond: {
                            $eq: [
                              '$$clear.report',
                              '6375856e1f7e265016ffd3c8', /* here i want to pass the reporId */
                            ],
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
                as: 'initiator',
              },
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                let: {
                  userId: '$peer.user', type: '$peer.type',
                },
                pipeline: [
                  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$userId'] } } },
                  {
                    $project: {
                      color: '$colorCode.code',
                      avatar: 1,
                      type: '$$type',
                      clear: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: '$clear',
                          as: 'clear',
                          cond: {
                            $eq: [
                              '$$clear.report',
                              '6375856e1f7e265016ffd3c8', /* same here */
                            ],
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
                as: 'peer',
              },
            },
            {
              $unwind: '$initiator',
            },
            {
              $unwind: '$peer',
            },
          ],

          as: 'operation',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$operation',
      },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $addFields stage to add a new field that holds the report id and then use the newly added field in subsequent stages.

```js
const reportId = '123someReportId'; //Replace this with the actual report id
const reports = await Report.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      reportId: '$_id', // Add a new field 'reportId' that holds the report id
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
    //..... continue
```

Then you can use this reportId field in the subsequent stages

```js
$lookup: {
  from: 'users',
  let: {
    userId: '$initiator.user',
    type: '$initiator.type',
    reportId: '$$reportId', // Pass the report id here
  }
```

Use as required...

```js
cond: {
  $eq: ['$clear.report', '$$reportId'], 
},
```

Comment: i did exactly as you said, but it gave me the error `Use of undefined variable: reportId`, so I passed it first to `operations` stage before `users` stage and it didn't give any error but the query retured with an empty array of `clear` field, which should return with one object inside the array

Comment: i have updated the answer. I have added this line to the top, const reportId = '123someReportId'; //Replace this with the actual report id

Comment: can you explain more about how this modification should help me to get the right query beside this query is about fetching all member reports not a single report so I need the report id to be dynamic, not static, and also about adding the report id to `operations` stage is it correct or wrong step?